# qstring double quotes and escape character qt

Tags: qt5, qstring

Good afternoon, I want to create a string type :

```
"{\" events \ ": [" in qt 5,
```

but creating

```
**QString (QLatin1String ("\"% 1 \ "")) .arg (str);**
```

does not make me the quote after the `{` or bar `\`.
Any ideas ?, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what result string do you want to create?

A: `"{\" events \ ": ["` use: `'''"{\\" %s \ ": ["''' % 'events'`

B: `"{" events ": ["` use: `'''"{" %s ": ["''' % 'events'`

C: `"{ events : ["` use: `'''"{ %s : ["''' % 'events'`

Comment: No need to use QString!